# Dropdown/Select list of Grails SpringSecurity property?

Tags: grails, spring-security, selectlist, domain-model

I am currently working on a Grails project and would like to know the best way of showing a select list of objects from the Spring Security domain model:

I know how to create a select list but I just want to find out the best way within grails to populate it with the objects from that domain. I was thinking of calling something like "**user.list(params)**" and then passing that to the view, I could then access the defined object within that domain, but im not 100% sure wether that is the best way or if it can be done that way?

Thanks in advance

EDIT.....

I have the following custom model setup in the controller:

```
class UserModel {
           String username
           String firstName
           String lastName

           def email = User.email.list()
           String[] emails = email

           static constraints = {
                username blank: false
                firstName blank: false
                lastName blank: false

           }
}
```

Then when the index page for this view is initialized I pass this to it:

```
[model: new UserModel(copy)]
```

and finally on the view i have this:

```
<g:select name="emails" from="${model.emails}"
```

Now when I run the application I get this error:

```
No signature of method: grails.plugins.springsecurity.ui.UserModel.propertyMissing() is applicable for argument types: () values: [] Possible solutions: propertyMissing(java.lang.String)
```

Can anyone please help with this?? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been working hard at this and have implemented a solution for the issue I was having and it all works fine. Below is what I have in my controller for the view in question:

```
def index = {
        [userList: Users(), command: new RegisterCommand(copy)]
    }

protected List Users() {
        lookupUserClass().list()
    }
```

The List Users calls another function from an extended class which is shown below:

```
protected Class<?> lookupUserClass() {
        grailsApplication.getDomainClass(lookupUserClassName()).clazz
    }
```

This view then renders the list of items that I want to show in a select list:

```
<g:select name="emails" from="${userList.emails}" />
```

You can also do this if you are looking for unique values:

```
<g:select name="emails" from="${userList.emails.unique()}" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You approach looks absolutely correct. In the controller action you populate the model:

```
def listUsers = {
    [ 'users': Users.list( params ) ]
}
```

and in the view you use the model for populating the listbox:

```
<g:select name="users" from="${ users }" />
```

Your issue looks very simple, so I hope, I've got the idea behind the question correctly :-)

Comment: I already have a model being passed to the view, I am presuming its not possible to pass another model to the view and only a mapped model which i dont have

Comment: I need to add the list of say User E-Mails as a String[] in that custom model and then when the whole model is passed to the view i populate the slect list from the model.e-mails. How would I do this?